# Count hash values while using Data::Dumper

Tags: perl, hash

I need to find the count of values (ie abc1) in a Perl hash and if > 4 run run an internal command within a IF block. I just need to figure out the concept of how to count # of values.

(I could leave a code sample of what I've attempted but that would just result in uncontrolled laughter and confusion)

I am using `Data::Dumper`, and utilizing the following format to store key/value in hash.

```
push @{$hash{$key}}, $val;
```

A print of hash gives :

```
$ print Dumper \%hash;

    $VAR1 = {
      '5555' => [
                   'abc1',
                   'abc1',
                   'abc1'
                 ]
    };
```

Please let me know how to get the count.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Data::Dumper` prettifies the output of data structures like hash, it doesn't compute aggregates like count on that data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, do you want to count that particular string, or the number of elements?

```
my $count = @{$hash{$key}};   # get the size of the array (all elements)

my %num;
for my $val (@{$hash{$key}}) {
    $num{$val}++;             # count the individual keys
}
print "Number of 'abc1': $num{'abc1'}\n";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was not fully aware of dereference. I went through this link ( http://www.perlmeme.org/howtos/using_perl/dereferencing.html) and understood the concept.

Comment: You're welcome. When in doubt, remember that a hash key or array element can only ever be a scalar value.

Comment: For some reason, things are not working when value differs ( ie abc1, abc2, abc3, do I need to change something? 
        $ print Dumper \%hash;

    $VAR1 = {
      '5555' => [
                   'abc1',
                   'abc2',
                   'abc3'
                 ]
    };

Comment: Define "not working". Also, I gave you two solutions, which one are you referring to?

Comment: My bad - no issues wrt your solution - we're good in this. However, I am trying to compare other hash key('abc1') with value of above one('abc1'), and that does not seem to work. Any suggestion?

Comment: Yes. I suggest you quit saying "it doesnt work" because that tells me nothing.  I have no way of knowing what you are doing, so ask a new question with the full code.

Comment: Sure, I will ask a new question as suggested. No more questions for this query. Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 1):

The number of values in a hash is the same as the number of keys. What you are after, though, is the number of elements in an array (referenced from a hash value). To get the size of an array, just use it in scalar context. For an array reference, you have to dereference it first:

```
my $count = @{ $hash{$key} };
```